# Do you get a special achievment or upgrade if you defeat all 4 legendary ships in AC4?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I was wondering if you get an achievment or special upgrade if you defeat the legendary ships at the corners of the map in Assassins Creed: Black Flag?

It would really help if you knew or had some idea!

Comment: Why don't you find out for yourself? Let the game surprise you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If you manage to fight through all the Legendaries, apart from the large monetary rewards (don't forget to loot the packages for the money); finishing all four battles will also give the Jackdaw the additional move of a speed ram, where aiming forward and pressing X (PS) and A (Xbox) will allow the Jackdaw to dash for a moment for a raw with increased power."

Here is the complete guide for them: http://m.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-4-black-flag/Legendary_Ships

Comment: @Jamd Defeating all legendary ships awards you the [Devil of the Caribbean achievement](http://www.trueachievements.com/a180155/devil-of-the-caribbean-achievement.htm). Also, do you really get the Charge move only after defeating all of them? Since the move belongs to El Impoluto, I thought you'd get it after defeating him (I refuse to address a ship as "her" that carries an obviously male name) alone. Since he was the last of the legendary ships I defeated, I can't for certain.

Comment: @Nolonar: I've defeated that one but not the twins and I have certainly not been notified of a charge move so I assume I don't have it.